# how to create "sample file" for the qAlign() function after trimming the reads in R

Tags: r, rna-seq, sequence-alignment, homework

I'm an absolute beginner trying to solve this question "Align the trimmed and untrimmed reads using QuasR and plot alignment statistics, did the trimming improve alignments?"

I did trim the reads using the preprocessReads() function, now I want to align the output but the qAlign() only takes a samples file and genome file. however, my trimmed reads are two separate files how can I align them.

I asked google but I didn't find the answer

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please consider the answer below and whether you wish to upvote/accept.

Answer (score 1):

[The QuasR vignette](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/QuasR/inst/doc/QuasR.html) tells you how to run it. The samples file should contain a list of your samples and fastq files.